# How to determine if a function is of a specific asymptotic type in algorithm analysis?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

I'd like to have a better understanding of the asymptotic notation and how can one classify whether a function is of O notation of another function, and how can we tell whether **`f = o(g) || f != o(g)`**

For example:

---

[image]

---

For example, how can we tell that **`f = O(g)`**?

I've seen mostly this approach (solution below is unrelated to the question above):

[image]

But this is confusing as I don't undertand the way the prove this.

Please help me understand the core concept that is being applied here.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We say that  f is O(g) if we can find these two things:

(1) We can find a constant "C" (You pick only one constnat , here i mean you can't change it later, this is most confusing part for beginners).

(2) And a "N" (This is some lower bound, means for values greater than this N, our formula will be valid, once you reach end then come back and try to understand i mean by lower bound).

such that whenever we plug in the value of n>= N then f(n) should be less or equal to C.g(n)

Or in formula form:

[image]

Example:

let's say i have a function `f = 3n^2 + 4n + 3`

and one more function `g = n^2`

Is f = O(g)?

The leading term of f is `3n^2` , it means if i have a constant higher than `3` and i multiply it with `g` then `f` will be less than `g`.

Let's take `n = 4 > 3` then i get `g = 4n^2` and my constant `c` is then `4`.

Now the question is what happends if i increase the value of `n`? If i plug in for example `n = 4` then `f(n)` will not be less than `g(n)` but when i insert `n = 5` then it is valid. so in this example `c = 4 and N = 5`.

Now you have two different things in your question. This question below has nothing to do with Big-O notation , it's called `tilde notation`.

Big-O throws constant terms away but tilde does not. It's more stricter form for the comparisons of algorithms. Here `22` means whenever n approaches infinity, the difference between f and g is approximately 22. However i prefer `tilde` notation but first you need to understand Big-O then you can go further.

[image]

For your this question :
[image]

You can see: both function have higher terms `n` namely `f = 7n + ...` and `g = n`.
If i want to prove is `f is o(g)`

Now if i ask for what value `c` `c.g(n)` is greater than `f(n)`.
Does there exist any constant `c` such that the formula is valid for all `n >= some N`.

If i multiply `g` now with `7` (because f has leading constant 7) would this be valid? No because f has also factor of 8 with it, it means i need to increase constant `c`. Let's take it as `8` then still `7n + 8 > 8n` if `n = 1` but what happends when `n >= 2` then `g` is always greater than `f`. So for constant `c = 8 and n >= 2` `f is o(g)`. You can also prove also that `g is  O(f)`.
This is not difficult, you should get constant `c = 1 and for n belonging to natural number`

Comment: Thank you Luai for your descriptive answer. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

A function `f` on natural numbers is Big-Oh of a function `g` on natural numbers, written `f(n) = O(g(n))`, if and only if there exist constants `c > 0, n_0 > 0` such that, for `n >= n_0, f(n) <= c * g(n)`. To prove this, you must show values for `c` and `n_0` that work and show that they work. You can show that `7*n + 8 = O(n)` because `7*n + 8 <= 8n` for all `n >= 8 (c = 8, n_0 = 8)`. You can show that `n = O(7*n + 8)` because `n <= 1 * (7*n + 8)` for `n >= 1 (c = 1, n_0 = 1)`.

A function `f` on natural numbers is Little-Oh of a function `g` on natural numbers, written `f(n) = o(g(n))`, if and only if for all constants `c > 0`, there exists an `n_0` such that `f(n) < cg(n)` for `n >= n_0`. To prove this, you must show how to find a `n_0` that works given any positive value of `c`. You can show that `7*n + 8 = o(n^2)` because `7*n + 8 < c*n^2` can be rearranged to `c*n^2 - 7*n - 8 > 0`, which clearly has solutions for any positive choice of `c` (the derivative is `2*c*n - 7` which is eventually always positive, so the function must get positive for a large enough `n_0`).